# How can packers work despite mechanisms like Data Execution Prevention?

Tags: packers

Modern operating systems have memory protections such as Data Execution Prevention, No Execute bit for Data, Read-only bit for text/code sections etc.
I don't understand how packers work when these memory protections are in place.
Where do the packers unpack the compressed/encrypted binaries when the code pages are marked Read-Only and data pages are marked for No Execute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The unpacker will request a page of memory from the OS that is marked write and unpack the code into there. Once the unpacking is done it will use [VirtualProtect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on windows or [mprotect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) on posix compliant systems to change the protection bits to read-only and execute (or allocate the page as read-write+execute in the first place and skip making it read+execute-only).

In other words the application gets enough control over the protection bits to do run-time code generation.

Comment: Or (for Windows), unpack into an existing PE section whose characteristics are marked as RWX, thus having the PE loader do the page protection work.